# auto-connect nearby connectors in imported draw.io file?

Tags: sequence-diagram, flowchart, draw.io, diagrams.net

I am importing flowcharts from another platform and most of the objects come through intact, but connectors are not attached to their intended shapes. Manually connecting every one of these lines is tedious and this is a frequent task for me. Is there an easy way to automatically connect the floating connectors to nearby shapes?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to automatically connect connectors to nearby shapes.